# YII2.Выдаёт 404 ошибку на внутренних страницах

Tags: php, yii2

При переходе к примеру по адресу `site/404` показывает страницу 404 ошибки в дизайне сайте.
А если перейти на внутренних страницах, к примеру по адресу `site/product/404`, то выдаёт `Not Found (#404)` на белом экране.
Подскажите, как это настроить, чтобы на внутренних страницах 404 страница корректно показывалась в дизайне сайта?

**P.S.**

```
<?php

define('URL_TRANSFORMER_DYNAMIC', 'dinamic');
$skip = array('.', '..');
$modules = [];
$files = scandir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../modules');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (!in_array($file, $skip) && is_dir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../modules/' . $file)) {
        $modules[$file] = ['class' => 'app\modules\\' . $file . '\Module'];
    }
}   

$config = [
    'id' => 'acms',
    'name' => 'ACMS 9',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'language' => 'ru',
    'sourceLanguage' => 'ru',
    'modules' => $modules,
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => '5bdV2clPQw7gpZ-Vt6yI5yNVQMXBZUkw',
            'baseUrl' => '',
            'enableCsrfValidation' => false,
        ],

        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\modules\admin\models\Admin',
            'class' => 'yii\web\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'loginUrl' => ['admin/auth/login'],
            'idParam' => '__id_admin',
        ],
        'assetManager' => [
            'basePath' => '@webroot/assets',
            'forceCopy' => YII_DEBUG,     
            'baseUrl' => '@web/assets',
        ],

        'image' => [
            'class' => 'app\components\image\ImageComponent',
        ],
        'event' => [
            'class' => 'app\components\Event',
        ],
        'email' => [
            'class' => 'app\components\Email',
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => false,
            'showScriptName' => true,
            'rules' => [
                'acms' => 'admin/admin/login',
                '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
                '' => 'site/index',
                '<action>' => 'site/<action>'
            ],
        ],
        /*
        'assetManager' => [
            'basePath' => '@webroot/assets',
            'forceCopy' => YII_DEBUG,
            'baseUrl' => '@web/assets',
        ],
        */
        'i18n' => [
            'translations' => [
                'app' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                    'sourceLanguage' => 'ru',
                    'fileMap' => [
                        'app' => 'app.php',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
        'cache' => require(__DIR__ . '/cache.php'),
        // (optionally) you can configure logging
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'logFile' => '@app/runtime/eauth.log',
                    'categories' => ['nodge\eauth\*'],
                    'logVars' => [],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'params' => require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
];

if (YII_DEBUG) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';

    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        'allowedIPs' => ['*'],
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = 'yii\gii\Module';
}

return $config;
```

Answer (score 1):

В конфиге нужно прописать:

```
'errorHandler' => [
    'errorAction' => 'site/error',
]
```

Тогда любая ошибка будет вызывать этот экшн и все ошибки будут выводиться в вашем шаблоне. Подробнее https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-erroraction

Соответственно, в `SiteController` ошибки будет обрабатывать `actionError`

Comment: добавил в вопрос файл web.php конфига `errorHandler`  там был, но всё равно выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Возможно, проблема в настройке веб сервера. Видимо, не все запросы идут на index.php